# Calendar app from google not available

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calendar, google-calendar

I just upgrade my Samsung Galaxy s2 and was expecting to use the new Calendar app from Google itself. Here is a screenshot

http://cdn.pocket-lint.com/images/4zGC/google-android-ice-cream-sandwich-review-14.jpg?20111121-150627

It seems not to be included in the upgrade and strangely enough not downloadable from the play store.

I searched the net but it seems everyone can use it cause I see no similar reports. Is it available on your ICS android phone?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Was this an official over the air (OTA) update from your carrier or Samsung, or did you manually install a leaked ROM?

Comment: It was an official update with kies on the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That calendar app is the default included in AOSP. Carrier and manufacturer customizations frequently replace the AOSP variants in favor of modified versions.
This is what's happened with the Galaxy SII updates. Instead of vanilla android you received Touchwiz.

If you'd like it on your phone, you can install it from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.calendar&hl=en) or flash a custom rom like [Cyanogemod](http://cyanogenmod.com) or [AOKP](http://aokp.co).

Comment: I found that out after a while, you are correct. The people who want it on the out of the box Galaxy S2 can install Android 4 ICS Calendar https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.concentriclivers.calendar&hl=en
(AOSP = Android Open Source Project)